# Hoes does setRange in GAE datastore work?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I need to mark the first(earliest) 10 entries in my table as '1'. How to do this?

I read about query.setRange(0,10) option. I just want to confirm whether this setRange option without any sort applied retrieves the earliest 10 entities of a table?

I don't want to save any date and time to measure this.
If you have some other simpler way to do this, please advise.

Thanks,
Karthick.

Answer (score 2):

You should never count on a database (no matter which one) to sort results without explicitly requesting a specific order. Even if datastore returns the earliest entities, it might change in the future and your software will stop working.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Thanks for the advise.